# What happened to apport's "examine locally" button?

Tags: apport, ubuntu-wiki

According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash an application crash should be examined further using the "Examine locally" button from Apport:

[image]

That button is no longer in the 16.04LTS version of that dialog:

[image]

At the help page for the Wiki, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HelpContents
the instructions for reporting wiki errors read "If you find any errors on the help pages, please describe them on HelpErrata." "HelpErrata" is a link to http://moinmoin.wikiwikiweb.de/HelpErrata which leads to a 404 error. That's the wrong place to link anyway; that's for MoinMoin Wiki system bugs, not errors on the help pages.

Answer (score 3):

I'd seen the same in a fresh Ubuntu 17.04 install; after installing `apport-retrace` the missing button was seen.

Running the command

```
apt policy apport-retrace
```

will tell you  whether the package is installed.

To install, run

```
sudo apt-get install apport-retrace
```